# drive permissions problem

Tags: partitioning, permissions, ntfs, drive

I seem to be unable to write to my drives (NTFS). they worked fine until today, not sure what happened.

`UUID=xxxxxxxxx /media/stuff ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000 0 0`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT The drive is currently mounted as follows:

```
/dev/sdb2 on /media/stuff type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
```

Comment: Please enter the command `mount` in a terminal and paste the lines pertaining to the NTFS drive in your question. This will give us the current situation instead of the desired situation from `fstab`.

Comment: /dev/sdb2 on /media/stuff type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)  is this what you mean?

Comment: The drive is mounted read-only, for whatever reason. Please try to unmount it and remount it read-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a dual-boot system with Windows just turned off fast startup mode in windows and you will be able to write to NTFS drive. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup.

Comment: Absolutely incredible.... thanks a bunch.... I have no clue why it messed with linux, as I have been running a dual boot for some time now without any issues.